# Liferay : How to receive the parameters of renderURL through a Portlet class

Tags: liferay-6

I read that the renderURL will be responsible to execute the renderPhase only (That is the doView Method of the  java class )

Now in one of the JSP i have a Hyper Link to navigate to the another page as shown 
(This is the starting page of the Portlet)

```
 <a href="<portlet:renderURL>
  <portlet:param name="goto" value="IpByHourPage"/>
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/page2.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>">
Click here to go to Second Page
</a>
```

Now my question is that , is it possible taht instead of getting the  parameters inside the page2.jsp and processing it , is it possible that to recieve these parameters inside the java file that is

I want to recieve this parameters inside the SecondPort as shown below .

**For example**

```
public class SecondPort extends MVCPortlet {
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse  throws IOException, PortletException 
{

// do something in this code here .

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get your parameter set in `<portlet:param>` tag in your portlet class.
You can read that parameter in `doView` method by following :-

```
public class SecondPort extends MVCPortlet {
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse  throws  
IOException, PortletException 
{
   String goto = renderRequest.getParameter("goto");
   String jspPage= renderRequest.getParameter("jspPage");      

    //Do something here....
}
```

like this..